# How add effect to Media Recorder in android?

Tags: android

I Search everywhere i dont find anything.

how add effect on file audio in android?

This is my code...

```
  mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(180000);
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(50000);
        } else {
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(50000);
        }

        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(50000);
        mOutputFile = getOutputFile();
        mOutputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());


        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(50000);
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(50000);
        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
            mStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mTickExecutor, 100);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

Thank you very much if you help me!!!!!!

Comment: I don't think you can do this simply using the media recorder. You might have to go deeper and use the AudioCodec class, (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioCodec.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** : library called [Sonic](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic/blob/master/doc/index.md). Its basically for Speech as it use PSOLA algo to change pitch and tempo. But its ok.

by this library you can speeding up or slowing down speech and change the voice to child or woman or granny.